# Linq to Entities Group By issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a sales database that records in a CountryCode column the 2 character country code of where a good was sold. In the sales database, there is no quantity column, basically every row represents 1 sale, and the information associated with that sale.

I was to be able to display the top selling countries. Here is the linq query I have come up with:

```
List<TopSellingCountries> tsc = (from sale in Sales
                                 where sale.CountryCode != null
                                 group sale by sale.CountryCode into cc
                                 select new TopSellingCountries
                                 {
                                     CountryCode = cc.Select(c => c.CountryCode).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     CountryCount = cc.Count()
                                 }).OrderByDescending(c => c.CountryCount).Take(10).ToList();
```

When I output this to my View however, I get a table with the following information:

```
CountryCode | CountryCount
         US | 196
         IE | 168
         US | 99
         GB | 91
         IE | 57
         AU | 32
         GB | 22
         AU | 18
         CA | 17
         CA | 17
```

As you can see it doesn't seem to be grouping properly by country code. Does anyone have any ideas how I can overcome this?

EDIT:
Here is the code from the View if anyone needs it:

```
<table class="normal">
    <tr>
        <th>Country Code</th>
        <th>Country Count</th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.TopSellingCountries)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%: item.CountryCode %></td>
        <td><%: item.CountryCount %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is the data type of CountryCode?  Is it possible there are trailing spaces on some of the records?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. I'll have to investigate :S Just wanted to make sure the code was okay.

Comment: Is the CountryCode just a simple `get; set;`. If it is more complex and the result differs if you request it twice from the same object, you need to fix that first

Comment: @cadrell0 - you were right, it was trailing spaces! Just shows you can never rely on external information. Thanks!

Comment: @109221793 I posted a solution that will trim the excess spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you trim excess spaces off of the CountryCode

```
List<TopSellingCountries> tsc = (from sale in Sales
                                 where sale.CountryCode != null
                                 group sale by sale.CountryCode.Trim() into cc
                                 select new TopSellingCountries
                                 {
                                     CountryCode = cc.Key,
                                     CountryCount = cc.Count()
                                 })
                                 .OrderByDescending(c => c.CountryCount)
                                 .Take(10)
                                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
CountryCode = cc.Key,
```

instead of

```
CountryCode = cc.Select(c => c.CountryCode).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Also trimming the CountryCode can prevent problems like this:

so:

```
group sale by sale.CountryCode.Trim() into cc
```

Comment: Ok thats the first thing which came up but it is still an (performance and readability) improvement. Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following

```
List<TopSellingCountries> tsc = (from sale in Sales
                                 where sale.CountryCode != null
                                 group sale by sale.CountryCode into cc
                                 order by cc.Count() descending
                                 select new TopSellingCountries
                                 {
                                     CountryCode = cc.Key,
                                     CountryCount = cc.Count()
                                 }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't even make sense.  What would only getting 10 records help?  Why 10?  And what benefit is there to adding an order by?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice the ording or the sorting int the original query.  They were cut off because I had to scroll.